# The sum of the solutions of $\sin\left(2x\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ over the interval$ [–π, d]$ is$–π.$ find the value of $d$

Tags: trigonometry

The sum of the solutions of $\sin\left(2x\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ over the interval$  [–π, d]$ is$–π.$ find the value of $d$

I think the first thing I must know is the number of solutions. I know that $x=\:\frac{\pi }{6},\frac{\pi }{3}$, but how can I deduce how many more? How can I utilize $-\pi$ is the domain? What is the general approach to these kinds of questions?

Multiple choice options:

The options are

$a) o$,

$b)\frac{\pi }{6}$,

$c)\frac{3\pi }{4}$,

$d)\frac{7\pi }{6}$,

$e) \frac{3\pi }{2}$

Comment: The value of $d$ is not uniquely defined.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I apologise this is actually a multiple choice question. The options available are now included. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions in

$$[-\pi,\infty)$$ are

$$-\frac{5\pi}6,-\frac{2\pi}3,\frac\pi6,\frac\pi3,\frac{7\pi}6,\frac{4\pi}3,\cdots$$

and if you accumulate them you obtain

$$-\frac{5\pi}6,-\frac{3\pi}2,-\frac{4\pi}3,-\pi,\frac\pi6,\frac{3\pi}2\cdots$$

Comment: Oh okay, this is actually a multiple choice question

Comment: The options are $a) o$,  $b)\frac{\pi }{6}$,  $c)\frac{3\pi }{4}$, $d)\frac{7\pi }{6}$, $e) \frac{3\pi }{2}$

Comment: @Negrawh There is enough information in Yves Daoust's answer to find out.